# Does the sentence 'Boy, are my arms tired' mean 'Boy, my arms are tired.'?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, exclamations

I found a meme that says 'I flew in from (wherever) and boy are my arms tired!'. I can understand what's funny about this meme but I can't understand why 'are my arms tired!' is used instead of 'my arms are tired!'. that's not an interrogative sentence, right? why does there have to be an inversion?

Comment: You are correct. It is a declarative statement.  There is no question implied in the phrase.

Comment: To the extent that it's an "interrogative", it's a ***rhetorical*** question (with the "built-in" answer ***Yes**, your arms are **definitely** tired!*)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You need to make this <s>an</s> **the** answer.

Comment: @Greybeard: I knew there was another more appropriate term than "interrogative" when I wrote that comment, but I couldn't think what it was. Thanks to Edwin, I now realise "le mot juste" is in fact ***interjection***. But the actual *question* being asked here isn't really suitable for ELU anyway - it's essentially an ELL-level question.

Comment: The "mot" in question is "rhetorical".

Comment: @Greybeard: Looking at [Should rhetorical questions end with a period?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/), I'm now thinking you're probably right. But the fact that I couldn't identify the "correct" terminology without all this help from others does rather suggest I should leave it to others to address the "terminological" aspect of the Q! :)

Answer (score 7):

After a short interjection of amazement / delight / relief / exhaustion, inversion is not uncommon *but only with a limited subset of interjections*:

> - "Wow, is she having fun!" [[YouTube; Grandma sledding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMbFI4IccSo)]
> - "Gosh, was he a looker!" [[Facebook, via Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Gosh%2C+was+he%22&ei=DwZvYNpkpv_v9Q_E_ZigCA&oq=%22Gosh%2C+was+he%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAgQHjIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzoJCAAQsAMQCBAeOgsIABCwAxAIEAoQHjoICAAQsAMQhgM6CAgAEAgQBxAeOgoIABAIEAcQChAeOggIABAHEAUQHlDselisfWDSgQFoAXAAeACAAVuIAakCkgEBNJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiaqMqx4e7vAhWm_7sIHcQ-BoQQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)
> - "They beg but man are they cute!" [[Tripadvisor.com / Santo_Domingo](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g147289-i18439103-Santo_Domingo_Santo_Domingo_Province_Dominican_Republic.html)]
> - "Boy, am I glad to see you!" [[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms 2015](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/(boy%2C)+am+I+glad+to+see+you!)]

This is discussed in an article by [[Andersen and Aijmer in The Pragmatics of Society](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SSKKYO1YPBEC&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=%22This+inversion+of+standard+word+order+instantiates+one+type+of+exclamative%22&source=bl&ots=slfoJS0uph&sig=ACfU3U1HfBUcYiJQCiOcdSRPNFR1R3Owkw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV3f7mmbHzAhVDlFwKHe5rAC4Q6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22This%20inversion%20of%20standard%20word%20order%20instantiates%20one%20type%20of%20exclamative%22&f=false)]:

> Subject-Auxiliary Inversion (SAI) is one standard index of the exclamative clause type....  This inversion of standard word order instantiates one type of
> exclamative sentence and is itself a marker of emotional involvement
> ....

Occasionally, the inversion-form exclamatory appears without an overt interjection:

- "Am I glad to see you!"
- "Is he one lucky guy!"

Answer (score 1):

It does appear at first glance to be an interrogative due to the subject-auxiliary inversion. However, in this instance, the closed interrogative (yes/no question) indirectly conveys an exclamatory statement, the implicit meaning being close to that of the positive exclamative:

> How tired my arms are!

The understood meaning is that the speaker's arms are very tired.

Answer (score 1):

The intended meaning is "the astonishing degree to which my arms are tired is deserving of the exclamation »boy!«"

Comment: This is already given in other answers.  Please see the [help] and [tour], and welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 0):

> are my arms tired!

This is a rhetorical question. It is emphatic and humorous. Rhetorical questions do not take a question mark.