# Inversion — a really odd example

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, exclamations

In the book *Story Genius* by Lisa Cron we read:

> Even if she's only six, she already has a worldview that, like most of us, she's never even questioned—why should she? As far as she can see it's "just the way things are." Boy, **is she in for a rude awakening**. [...]

(Yes, punctuation's been double-checked)

My question, of course, pertains to **'is she in'**. How does this inversion find its explanation?

I guess it falls in what's taken as an **informal register**, but still I don't know if it's the matter of putting more stress on specific words or something else (intonation...?)

I would appreciate more examples like this from your smart linguistic heads and a word of explanation!

Comment: Does this help? [Does the sentence 'Boy, are my arms tired' mean 'Boy, my arms are tired.'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/564559/191178)

Comment: I hear it as a rhetorical question ... an assertion formed like *a question that answers itself*. The question introduces the inversion. *Can you believe that?*

Answer (score 1):

It is a form of exclamation.

> Boy, is it ever hot and humid today!
>
> Boy, is it hot today!

There's an underlying almost imperceptible question: "Wouldn't you agree?"

On the semantic level it's probably a close cousin to

> Hot enough for you!?

Answer (score 0):

It's a statement, rather than a question, as the wording may seem to suggest. She is in for a rude awakening. It's a common way to say it with a hint of sarcasm, because of course they aren't asking, they are saying. Like, "Boy, am I hungry *nom nom nom*".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think I need to reference common sayings like 'boy am i hungry'

Comment: Any internet search will shows plenty of examples, there's even a tiktok trend that shows up